# How to create pagination for custom taxonomy in Wordpress

Tags: custom-taxonomy, pagination

my code it's this, and i can't create the pagination for that, its working good the pages 1, 2, 3 and etc.. but its just that the pagination links are not showing in the template.

I created a template for show all the custom taxonomies with the pictures and etc.. its just that not appear's the numbers of pagination but its working the pages writing manual.

my code its this.

```
<?php
            // Get the taxonomy's terms
$terms = get_terms(
    array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'girls',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'orderby' => 'count',
        'order'      => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'number' => 5,
    )
);

// Check if any term exists
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && is_array( $terms ) ) {
    // Run a loop and print them all
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="pornstars-box-stars">
                      <div class="video-pornstar">
                        <a class="estrella-enlace" href="<?php echo bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>?girls=<?php echo $term->slug; ?>" title="<?php echo $term->name; ?>">
<?php
                    $image_id  = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'girls-image-profile', true );
                    $cat_image = wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, 'video-thumb' );
                    if ( $cat_image ){
                      echo $cat_image;
                    }else{
                      $thumb_url = '';
                      if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        $thumb_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_id(), 'video-thumb' );
                      } elseif ( '' !== get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'thumb', true ) ) {
                        $thumb_url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'thumb', true );
                      }
                      if ( empty( $thumb_url ) ) {
                        $thumb_url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/no-thumb.png';
                      }
                      echo '<img class="video-img img-fluid" data-src="' . esc_url( $thumb_url ) . '">';
                    }
?>                 
                      <span class="titulo-estrella"><?php echo $term->name; ?></span>
                          <div class="estrella-contador">
                            <?php echo intval( $term->count ) ?> videos
                          </div>
                      </a>                        
                      </div>
                    </div>  
                    </div>  

        <?php
    }
} ?>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="pagination">

        <div class="pagination-box">
         <?php pagination('«', '»'); ?>
        </div>
            
      </div>
```

Comment: Nika are you using a plugin to replace the standard WP pagination function?  If not, then you may want to check out two Codex pages, most Theme template files use the next/prev function that is explained here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination  BUT WP also offers a function called paginate_links() which is explained here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/   Outside of that I'm not aware of any WP function called pagination() which is why I asked about a plugin.....